# Automatic Wordpress installation?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, wordpress

I've been wondering about making a blog hosting site like blogspot as a bit of a hobby. I figure Wordpress would be ideal to use but I'm not 100% on a lot of things related to this. Can I simply create mysql databases and wordpress installs with php functions and keep it secure from possible hacks? Or would the server as a whole need its own software to handle this securely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wordpress Mu](http://mu.wordpress.org) 
is a better choice for such site.

Answer (score 0):

Most hosting packages come with one click install of Wordpress. I used to have a Netfirms plan that I got for $10! Just click and install as many Wordpress sites you need.

Security with Wordpress is very strong. They have been around and the software is mature. You wouldn't be exposing yourself to much danger by templating the site.

You can try Wordpress using the WAMP server.

Answer (score 0):

We created an open source script for this purpose, you can find it here http://buckhill.github.io/linux-package-installer-for-wordpress

We wrote an article on how to use it here: https://www.buckhill.co.uk/blog/how-to-automatically-install-wordpress-plus-plugins/6

If you want to contribute to the project, please go ahead :)